# 2 json сохранить измененные и отсутствующие данные в новый json файл

Tags: php, json

**Содержимое test.json**

```
{
  "data": {
    "accountid": [{
      "series": {
        "smart1": 5,
        "smart2": 17,
        "smart3": 0,
        "smart4": 1
      }
    }, {
      "series": {
        "smart1": 5,
        "smart2": 25,
        "smart3": 5,
        "smart4": 1
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

**Содержимое test1.json**

```
{
  "data": {
    "accountid": [{
      "series": {
        "smart1": 5,
        "smart2": 22,
        "smart3": 0,
        "smart4": 45
      }
    }, {
      "series": {
        "smart1": 8,
        "smart2": 49,
        "smart3": 5,
        "smart4": 1,
        "smart5": 43
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

**Скрипт, который проверяет 2 файла json и если находит изменение, выводит на экран.**

```
$json1 = file_get_contents('test.json');
$json2 = file_get_contents('test1.json');
$a = json_decode($json1, true);
$b = json_decode($json2, true);


function doublejson($a, $b, $strkey)
   {
     foreach ($a as $key => $value)
        {
            foreach ($b as $key2 => $value2)
            {
                if($key==$key2)
                  {
                    if(gettype($value) != "array")
                     {
                        if($value2!=$value)
                        {

                            $c.="<br>".$strkey.'"'.$key.'"'.":".'"'.$value.'"'." => ".$strkey.'"'.$key2.'"'.":".'"'.$value2.'"'."<br>";
                            break;
                        }
                         else
                          {
                            break;
                          }
                     }
                             else
                                 {
                                  $c.=doublejson($a[$key], $b[$key], $strkey.'"'.$key.'":');
                                  break;
                                 }
                  }
            }   

        }
    return $c;
    }  


echo "<pre>".doublejson($a, $b, "")."</pre>";
```

**Выводит следующее: только изменившиеся значения**

```
"data":"accountid":"0":"series":"smart2":"17" => "data":"accountid":"0":"series":"smart2":"22"

"data":"accountid":"0":"series":"smart4":"1" => "data":"accountid":"0":"series":"smart4":"45"

"data":"accountid":"1":"series":"smart1":"5" => "data":"accountid":"1":"series":"smart1":"8"

"data":"accountid":"1":"series":"smart2":"25" => "data":"accountid":"1":"series":"smart2":"49"
```

**Вопрос1: Как мне сохранить только изменившиеся данные с учетом вычитания value2-value1, должен сохранить в новый файл json такую структуру:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "accountid": [{
      "series": {
        "smart2": 5, // 22-17
        "smart4": 44  // 45-1
      }
    }, {
      "series": {
        "smart1": 3, // 8-5
        "smart2": 24 // 49-25
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

**Вопрос2: Какой код нужно дописать, чтобы сохранялось ключ-значение из второго json, которого нет в первом, должно получиться так:**

```
{
      "data": {
        "accountid": [{
          "series": {
            "smart2": 5, // 22-17
            "smart4": 44  // 45-1
          }
        }, {
          "series": {
            "smart1": 3, // 8-5
            "smart2": 24, // 49-25
            "smart5": 43 // этот ключ-значение отсутствует в первом json и должен сохраниться в новом файле json
          }
        }]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим ключи второго массива соответствуют первому, плюс могут быть новые.

1. Для удобства извлечем данные, которые непосредственно надо сравнивать (то есть сами массивы сравнения).
2. Берем попарно два таких массива  `$a, $b`.
3. Идем по массиву `$b`.
4. Если ключ в массиве `$a` отсутствует, то пропускаем.
5. Если есть, то сравниваем значения.  Если изменилось, вычитаем
6. Если не изменилось, удаляем из массива.
7. возвращаем результат с ключом `series`

-

```
function diff($a, $b){
    $a = array_column($a['data']['accountid'], 'series');   // 1
    $b = array_column($b['data']['accountid'], 'series');

    $result = array_map(function($a, $b){                   // 2 
            foreach($b as $k => &$v){                       // 3
                if(!isset($a[$k]))  continue;               // 4 
                if($a[$k] != $v) $v -= $a[$k];              // 5 
                else unset($b[$k]);                         // 6    
            }
            return ['series' => $b];                        // 7  
          }, $a, $b);

    return ['data' => ['accountid' => $result]];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает так как нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю, что это не совсем относится к задаче, но это нужно переписать, чтобы получить более аккуратный и читаемый код

Возможно я просто не совсем понимаю задачу, но это можно сделать одним циклом с рекурсией. Для задачи нам нужно взять взять массив, на который мы будем опираться. В нашем случае это второй (`$two`)
В начале каждой итерации необходимо проверить существование элемента в первом массиве: `isset($one[$key])`
Далее получить значение и проверить его тип. Вместо `gettype($val) == 'array'` можно использовать функцию `is_array`, которая вернет `bool`. То что нам сейчас нужно. Так как сама функиция ожидает на вход два массива, мы и будем проверять сразу два значения, являются ли они массивами. Это нужно, чтобы избежать неожиданных последствий в виде внезапного Warning

Это решение делает то же самое, что и решение [@teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran), но является более универсальным (хотя можно использовать только его функцию `array_map` с аргументами и получится почти то же самое):

```php
function findDoubleAndUnique($one, $two) {
    $double = [];

    foreach($two as $key => $val) {
        if(!isset($one[$key])) {
            $double[$key] = $val;
            continue;
        }

        $val2 = $one[$key];

        if(is_array($val) && is_array($val2)) {
            $double[$key] = findDoubleAndUnique($val2, $val);
        } else if ($val != $val2) {
            $double[$key] = $val - $val2;
        }
    }

    return $double;
}
```

Ну и использование:

```php
$json1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('1.json'), true);
$json2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('2.json'), true);

file_put_contents('out.json', json_encode(findDoubleAndUnique($json1, $json2), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, оба варианта верно записали новый файл *.json с нужной структурой. Хотел двоим присвоить зеленую галку, но только одному из вас засчитывается.